# Improving Newton's Inequalities using the Taylor Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, na.numerical-analysis

Newton's inequalities say that if $f(x) = \sum \binom{n}{k} a_k x^k$ is a polynomial with all real roots then $ a_k^2 > a_{k-1}a_{k+1}$.

The [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_inequalities) this result uses that if $f(x)$ has all real roots, so do $df/dx$ and $x^{\deg f} f(1/x)$.  So we found two operations which preserve the class of all-real roots polynomials.  Then we can reduce to a quadratic.

Proving $df/dx$ has all real roots use Rolle's theorem, since

$$ f'(\xi) = \frac{f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)}{x_{k+1}-x_k} = 0$$

can be applied for $k = 1, \dots, n-1$.

---

I noticed the converse is not true.  Newton's inequalities does not imply all real roots (though I can't think of counterexample).

Can we improve Newton's inequalities by using one of the Taylor formulas?

$$ f(x) = f(0) + x \, f'(0) + \tfrac{x^2}{2}f''(\xi) \hspace{0.25in} \text{for}\hspace{0.25in} 0 < \xi < 1$$

Possibly the notion of discriminant $(r_1 - r_2)^2$ should also have to be generalized, and I don't know any real algebraic geometry for that.

---

In a paper by [Jim Pitman](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~pitman/453.pdf) it is stated without proof that $f(x)$ has all real roots if $b_k = \binom{n}{k} a_k$ is a Polya frequency sequence (e.g. See [Karlin](http://msp.org/pjm/1961/11-3/pjm-v11-n3-p20-s.pdf)).  I wish to understand better the connection to total positivity.

Comment: First, you mean $a_k^2 \geq a_{k-1}a_{k+1}$ (*log concavity* / *strong unimodality*). But what is the question? Log concavity by itself says very little about the locations of the roots (e.g., if $f$ is a real polynomial with no positive real zeros and $f(1)> 0$, then there exists $n$ such that $(1+x)^n f$ is strongly unimodal---included is that the product has no negative coefficients, too).

Comment: @DavidHandelman Real roots $\to $ unimodal, but not the other way around.  So, what other *restrictions does real roots place on the coefficients*? Can we get a nice elementary proof using Rolle's theorem or Mean Value Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The following two references should help you answer some of the questions you are chasing.

1. [Wagner. *Multivariate stable polynomials: Theory and applications*](http://www.ams.org/bull/2011-48-01/S0273-0979-2010-01321-5/) -- surveys several results of Borcea and Brändén (among others)
2. [Pemantle. *Hyperbolicity and real stable polynomials*](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/hyperbolic.pdf) -- this paper, especially **Section 4.2** in it contains the connections to PF functions, stability, ultra log-concavity, etc.